# Too Many Child context Mule 4

Tags: mule

Can any one suggests the best way to page through an API in Mule 4? The examples I saw used a choice with a flow reference to call the flow again in a loop. This API doesn't return the total number of records or pages so need to loop through each page until it returns an empty payload.

But if I call the same flow recursively, its throwing too many child context error.
What is the ideal way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same kind of scenario recently. I have done a recursive call using another flow to call the parent flow. If you use a flow reference from the same flow it will not allow you to do so.

In the child flow, I have incremented the next start index as well.
[image]

If you are looking for paging from the API level, you can accept the start index and the Page size as the two parameters. This call can go until the number of records < page size OR the API returns 0 records.